# Moving several files to different folders with same name

Tags: shell

I have some data for several stations that are separated for the station they are in, and the day they were recorded, so for station 1, for example, I have multiple folders called `2019.001,2019.002` etc. and inside these folders I have the files (all with the same name) ending with HHZ. What I have done is getting these files from each of the stations and putting them on another folder while renaming them to have the name of the folder above and maintaining the name of the station, afterwards I created the folders corresponding to their names. My actual question is how to move the files that correspond to the same day, e.g. `2019.001.station1` and `2019.001.station2` to the folder `2019.001`.

```
dir0=`pwd`
mkdir -p data || exit 1
for pathname in $dir0/stam/*/*HHZ; do
    cp "$pathname" "data/$( basename "$( dirname "$pathname" )" )STAMHHZ"
done

for pathname in $dir0/macu/*/*HHZ; do
    cp "$pathname" "data/$( basename "$( dirname "$pathname" )" )MACUHHZ"
done


cd $dir0/data
mkdir 2019.0{10..31}
mkdir 2019.00{1..9}
```

If there is also another way of executing the part of the code where I take the files so I can generalize for several stations that would be nice, since I am only working with two stations right now but in the future I'll work with more.

Here is the tree to where the data is

```
macu
├── 2019.001
│   └── MACUHHZ
├── 2019.002
│   └── MACUHHZ
├── 2019.003
```

And

```
stam
├── 2019.001
│   └── STAMHHZ
├── 2019.002
│   └── STAMHHZ
├── 2019.003
│   └── STAMHHZ
```

So ideally the final situation would be:

```
data
├── 2019.001
│   ├── 2019.001MACUHHZ
│   └── 2019.001STAMHHZ
```

And so on

Comment: In your edit, you missed two "dados" in the `cp` commands. Also, it might be helpful to provide a graph of the directory tree (both the original and the target). See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147467

Comment: Ok, thanks, it worked out fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script below creates the wanted file structure. The top level directories from which you want to copy data (in your example `macu` and `stam`) should be added to the `top_dir` variable. You can also change it to use a wildcard, or read them from a file, etc.

The basic idea is simple: For each top level directory, for each data directory, create the corresponding directory in `data`, and for each file, copy the file.

`pushd` and `popd` are used as a simple hack to make the `*` wildcards do what we want. `$dir0` contains the root folder of the operation, so we always know where `data` is.

`set -e` is used to exit immediately if there is an error.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

top_dirs=( macu stam )

dir0="$(pwd)"

mkdir -p data

for dir in "${top_dirs[@]}" ; do
    pushd "$dir" >/dev/null

    for datadir in * ; do
        mkdir -p "$dir0/data/$datadir"
        pushd "$datadir" >/dev/null

        for file in *HHZ ; do
            cp "$file" "$dir0/data/$datadir/$datadir$file"
        done

        popd >/dev/null
    done

    popd >/dev/null
done
```